# Using MVVM with dependency Injection and Storyboard

Tags: ios, json, swift, mvvm, dependency-injection

I have a *viewController* which is designed in one page of **Storyboard** and is the *initial/main screen* of the app. I'm trying to get some data from the api, then update a collectionView on my screen. I did get data before, but now I'm trying to build a **MVVM** structure in the app.

The way I tried to convert the app to MVVM is basically; building a **ViewModel** and **initializing the** **ViewController** with the **ViewModel** using dependency injection. You can see my dependency injection as below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
//MARK: - Properties

private var viewModel: ViewControllerViewModel? = nil

//MARK: - Lifce Cycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
    
//    //MARK: - Init
init(with viewModel: ViewControllerViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
  }
}
```

But the problem is, my viewModel is not being initialized at all. I did put some breakpoints to init() of ViewModel, but they never get hit and ViewModel below never executes. What am I missing here in terms of MVVM design pattern?

```
class ViewControllerViewModel {

init() {

   }
}
```

NOTE: I'm calling the viewController on SceneDelegate as below. How can I initialize the ViewController with using storyboard as below?:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
        self?.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "PopularMovies", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
        self?.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    
}
```

**Pictures:**

- My viewController has nothing on it and is the initial viewController with 1 page. Just trying to understand why my viewModel is not being initialized at all while my ViewController is being initialized.
- 

[image: Main Storyboard]
[image: Main StoryBoard Class]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a Storyboard the coder init is called. Basically you are never calling your init.

You could pass the VM when creatinv the viewController like

```
let viewController = // init the VC
viewController.viewModel = viewModel // create the VM you want to pass here.
```

Comment: Hi. I've edited one part of the question. Can you check it out?

Comment: It goes the same in the SceneDelegate too.
You create a variable 
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "PopularMovies", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
then viewController.viewModel = viewModel that you can create above here
then  self?.window?.rootViewController = viewController
        self?.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Does it make sense?

Comment: I get it yes. But by doing that I'm not initializing the ViewController with the ViewModel. I'm just changing the value of the ViewModel property right?

Comment: Well yes, you can't really initialize it because you are using a storyboard, so the only way is to pass it like this, which should work just the same as you'd use your init.